# MPMoviePlayer audio breaking issue

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am playing video in MPMoviePlayer in my app,I am fetching the video from server.
If the video length is about 25sec or more,the audio gets break.Means while playing the video when it reaches half then there is no audio can be heared.But if I seek the progess bar,audio again comes.

Can any one help me in this ?

```
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[moviePlayerController setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
[[self.moviePlayerController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 72, 320,180)];
[[self view] addSubview: [self.moviePlayerController view]];
self.moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;

 NSString *strng = @"http://qdemo_videos.s3.amazonaws.com/1360582540.mp4";
 NSURL * adurl = [NSURL URLWithString:strng];
 moviePlayerController.contentURL = url;
 moviePlayerController.controlStyle = YES;
 self.moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;
  [moviePlayerController play];
```

Comment: Test that exact video file / stream within your regular mobile safari browser to find out if the issue is connected to your code. Hint: it wont be your code but an encoding issue.

Comment: exactly..thank u till

How to make that fine ??

Comment: @NithinMK did u got the solution ?

Comment: yes..It was converting issue at server side

Answer (score -1):

If u are building on Xcode 4.6 or above and using iOS 6.0 or above then,

```
self.moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;
```

will not be called as its deprecated.

For further use this link:
Here's the doc 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Here's the explanation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html

And if it's not enough here is the code :) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW2

In my case setting the category to AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient did the trick!

Comment: How would an incorrect / unwanted AudioSession setup possibly force the video to lose its audio data while playing, recoverable by seeking back to the start? -> You should really read a question before attempting to answer it.

Comment: @Till I have presented my case and it seemed similar to me, theres no point of giving -1 to any answer if u cant give the correct one. Powers have been given to use it wisely not just madly as u r doing. I respect u as u are far much experienced to me but this is nort the way as u r behaving on this forum, its a knowledge sharing forum not any proprietry of urs so Mind It.

Comment: Please hover above that downvote button an read its text. This is not about being mad or anything personal. This is about an objective judgement on the usefulness of your answer in connection to the given question.